# Finding references to an image in a VS2010 solution?

Tags: image, visual-studio-2010, reference, find

I'm going through a solution in VS2010 and cleaning it up.

The solution contains a lot of images which are used nowhere.

What is the best way to find whether an image is used anywhere? Images could be referenced in markup, in config files, in code.

At the moment, I'm using the unsophiscated method of just Ctrl-Shift-F and typing the image name in to see if it shows up.

Is that the best way? Is there any where this method could fail (I delete something I shouldn't?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm am doing it the same way and don't think there is a better way to do it.